# How to Find Row with MAX value in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I need help with getting the name of a employee who is having maximum salary,
Tables:
employee (empid,empname)
emp_salary(empid,salary)

I need to get the empname from employee table who is having maximum salary which is in emp_salary.

I am bit confused in using inner join on sub query but not sure how to use it to accomplish this.

So far tried following but did not got results:

```
select e.emp_name,MAX(es.salary) 
from employee e 
inner join emp_salary es on e.emp_id=es.emp_id 
group by es.salary
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `TOP 1 - ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT TOP 1 e.*, es.salary       -- or TOP 1 WITH TIES
FROM employee e 
JOIN emp_salary es 
  ON e.emp_id=es.emp_id 
ORDER BY es.salary DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

TRY BELOW APPROACH

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP
(
Id INT,
Salary DECIMAL(18, 2)
)

INSERT INTO #TEMP (Id, Salary) VALUES (1, 10000)
INSERT INTO #TEMP (Id, Salary) VALUES (2, 10000)
INSERT INTO #TEMP (Id, Salary) VALUES (3, 5000)

CREATE TABLE #TEMP_Employee
(
Id INT,
Name nvarchar(100)
)

INSERT INTO #TEMP_Employee (Id, Name) VALUES (1, 'X')
INSERT INTO #TEMP_Employee (Id, Name) VALUES (2, 'Y')
INSERT INTO #TEMP_Employee (Id, Name) VALUES (3, 'Z')

DECLARE @MaxSalary decimal(18, 2), @sql nvarchar(max)
SELECT @MaxSalary  = Max(Salary) FROM #TEMP

set @sql = 
'SELECT 
T.Id, TE.Name
FROM 
#Temp T
INNER JOIN #TEMP_Employee TE ON TE.Id = T.Id AND T.Salary ='+convert(nvarchar(20), @MaxSalary)+';'


exec (@sql)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the tables are huge, the below query should help with performance, since you don't need to join the full table. Its more like a seek than scan.

```
;with cte as
(
    SELECT ID,salary,DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Salary deSC) AS DR   
    FROM EMPLOYEESALARY
)   
select TE.Name,C.Salary from CTE c
INNER JOIN EMPLOYEE TE ON C.Id = TE.Id
WHERE DR= 1
```